# Vb.Net & SQL Server Express : Create User for login throws error

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, authentication

We attached the database `PStorage` to the server.

Then I tried to create the login & user using the following code:

```
Dim con As New SqlConnection
Dim query As SqlCommand

con.ConnectionString = "Server=(LocalHost);Data Source=LocalHost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=PSTORAGE;Integrated Security=TRUE"

con.Open()

query.CommandText = "IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT [LoginName] FROM MASTER.DBO.SYSLOGINS WHERE [Name]='UserCP') CREATE LOGIN UserCP WITH PASSWORD='CPPassword'"

query.ExecuteNonQuery()
query.Dispose()

query.CommandText = "IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT [Name] FROM SYS.DATABASE_PRINCIPALS WHERE [Name]='CPUser') CREATE USER CPUser FOR LOGIN UserCP"

query.ExecuteNonQuery() 'This line is throwing the error -> Login Failed for the User 'UserCP'.
query.Dispose()
```

The error we are getting after executing the second query is

> Login failed for the user 'UserCP'

While attaching the database the same error occurs. Then we had to use `sqlCmd`.

In all the systems this method works fine. But in one of our customers system this problem occurs. What might be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of tries we could come to know that the folder was compressed [All the file names were in blue colour]. Since the database files were inside the compressed folder- none of the operations could be done on them perfectly.

1. Right click on the database folder, Press on **Properties**
2. Press on **Advanced**
3. Untick the **Compress contents to save disk space**
4. **Save** the changes made